# Is it possible to iterate over multiple containers with boost foreach?

Tags: c++, boost-foreach

I have two containers, and I need to iterate over them both at the same time, in the same loop. I'm using boost foreach.

Like so:

```
  #define foreach_ BOOST_FOREACH

  struct Vertex
  {
     int x;
     int y;
  }

  std::deque<Vertex>::iterator target_it = targets.begin();

  // Put items in correct position 
  foreach_(Vertex v, coords) 
  {
    v.y = (*target_it).y;
    target_it++;
  }
```

Where coords is a std::deque .

Can I also put `targets` into that `foreach` somehow? The doc suggests no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [Boost Zip Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to traverse the two in parallel.

Comment: what's about normal for each loop, can we travers two containers parallel ?

Comment: If you mean a range-based for loop, I think you're pretty much stuck with the same general idea (though nowadays, I'd probably use an `std::zip_view` rather than a Boost zip iterator).